# Button icon horizontal alignment with iconAlign: "top"

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS 4, I am attempting to create a vertically-oriented `ButtonGroup` with one button to start:

```
new Ext.ButtonGroup({
    columns: 1,
    region: "west",
    collapsible: false,
    defaults: {
      scale: "large",
      iconAlign: "top"
    },
    items: [{
      text: "Your Books",
      iconCls: "icon-books"
    } ]
  })
```

The CSS rule just specifies the background image:

```
.icon-books {
   background-image: url(/images/book_open.png) !important;
}
```

However, the image is flush left, as is illustrated below:

[image]

I'm quite the n00b with ExtJS, so I'm sure there's something obvious that I am missing. I would have expected `iconAlign: "top"` to align the image centered horizontally in addition to flush-top, but that's not what seems to happen. I am seeing the same effects on Firefox 6.0.2 and Chrome 13.0.

What config option or CSS rule am I missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: [here is a sample project](http://misc.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ExtJSButtonIssue.zip) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881758/contentprovider-with-multiple-tables

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a problem with the image itself, or some other css class is causing this problem. Ext Js automatically centers the icon when `iconAlign : 'top'` is set. Here's the what's written in the css:

```
.x-btn-text-icon .x-btn-icon-small-top .x-btn-text{
    background-position: center 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:18px;
}
```

When I tried this myself, I had no problems at all.

[image]

As you can see, the icon is aligned perfectly. Please check if some other css is interfering with the icon class defined by Ext

Comment: The images are plain 32x32 pixel PNG files. There is no manual CSS that would affect this element other than the rule you see above. If it matters, the `Button` is in a `ButtonGroup` in the `west` portion of a `BorderLayout` of a `Viewport`. I have added a link to a sample project demonstrating the problem. I am far from a CSS expert (which is why I'm using ExtJS in the first place), but I agree that things should be working from what I can tell. However, they aren't... :-) Thanks!

Comment: there is a problem with your `ext-all.css` file. According to the docs, "the image will be set as the background-image CSS property of the button by default, so if you want a mixed icon/text button, set `cls:'x-btn-text-icon'`)". In your `css` i can't find anything with `x-btn-text-icon` in it.

Comment: `x-btn-text-icon` does not exist anywhere in ExtJS 4.0.2a, except in the `sandbox` example.

Comment: I guess you could download the `ext-all.css` file and try again.. I don't use Ext JS 4, so I don't have a means of checking if there is a conflict in the version that you've download and what others are using. But as of ExtJS 3.3.1, `x-btn-text-icon` exists in the `css` as mentioned in the answered above. But from what is written in the documentation, I can only conclude that there seems to be some discrepancy in the version of `ext-all.css` that you're using. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For ExtJS 4.0, the following works for me: I have to override the default width of 16px as set by the x-... classes.

In my button I add my own custom class (note the 'star' class simply loads the background image).

```
iconCls: 'star backcenter'
```

And then set it to be centered, with the width:auto to override the 16px.  Magically it works for me.

```
.backcenter { 
   background-position:center  !important;
   width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iconAllign: top from extjs just sets the icon to be above the text, not centered. To make the item centered, you have to deal with the css...

```
.icon-books {
   background-image: url(/images/book_open.png) !important;
   background-position:center;

}
```

I think this should do it ...

Comment: That sounds believable, but it does not appear to have an impact. When looking at things in Firebug, the `background-position` in my `.icon-books` rule appears with strikethrough when highlighting the element. If I am understanding Firebug correctly, my request is overridden... but the override appears to be for `center top`, which would seem like it would give me what I want anyway. Yet, that's not the visual effect.

Comment: for me it works but for normal size icon... for scale large i checked the extj css and aparently it contains .x-btn-default-large-ml,{zoom:1;background-image:url('../../resources/themes/images/default/btn/btn-default-large-sides.gif');background-position:0 0} and the icon is displayed in the ml tag of the button div ... so maybe you can check if you have the same ,... i hope this helps

Comment: `scale` only seems to support `small`, `medium`, and `large`, not `normal`. I tried `medium` and still have the same visual effect, just smaller. I'll just switch to `iconAlign="left"` if I can't work out a solution. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I improve this issue by adding a css property (`style:{paddingLeft:'10px'}`) to button.

```
text:'<b>Cancel</b>',
name:'btCancel',
iconCls:'btCancel',
width:89,
height:37,
style:{paddingLeft:'10px'}
```