# ContentProvider with multiple tables

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-contentprovider

I want to implement a `ContentProvider` that manipulates multiple tables. Here is what I tried so far. I wrote a Java `Interface` that represents the CRUD operations that every table should implement in its CRUD class.

```
public interface CRUDHandler {
    //UPDATE
    int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,String[] selectionArgs);
    //READ
    Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) ;
    //CREATE
    Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values);
    //DELETE
    int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs);
    //get Mime type
    String getType(Uri uri);
}
```

Then I wrote an `abstract` `class` that defines a static `UriMatcher` for the `ContentProvider` so each class that `extends` this class should add its `Uri` that identifies it and provide an implementation for each method in interface.

The class looks like this:

```
public abstract class  ApplicationCRUD  implements CRUDHandler{

    public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

    static {
        sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    }
}
```

Further, I created a class for each table that `extends` this class and adds its `Uri`'s to the `UriMatcher` from the abstract class.

Here is an example:

```
public class Table1CRUD extends ApplicationCRUD {
    //Setup Projection Map for Table1 
        private static HashMap<String , String>sTable1ProjectionMap;
        static {
            sTable1ProjectionMap.put(ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData._ID, ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.TABLE_NAME+"."+ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData._ID);
            sTable1ProjectionMap.put(ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.COL1, ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.TABLE_NAME+"."+ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.COL1);
            sTable1ProjectionMap.put(ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.COL2, ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.TABLE_NAME+"."+ApplicationProviderMetaData.Table1MetaData.COL2);
        }

        public static final int INCOMING_SINGLE_URI_INDICATOR = 5;
        public static final int INCOMING_COLLECTION_URI_INIDICATOR = 6;
    static {
        //standard URI 
        sUriMatcher.addURI(ApplicationProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY, "t1", INCOMING_COLLECTION_URI_INIDICATOR);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(ApplicationProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY, "t1/#", INCOMING_SINGLE_URI_INDICATOR);
        //here add your custom URI 

    }
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now my `ContentProvider` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationProvider  extends ContentProvider{
    //Define TAG FOR EACH CLASS FOR DEBUGGING 
    private static final String TAG = "ApplicationProvider";
    // Application CRUD Handlers use to support multiple tables inside the content provider
    private static Table1CRUD table1CRUD;
    private static Table2CRUD table2CRUD;

    static {
        table1CRUD = new Table1CRUD();
        table2CRUD= new Table2CRUD();

    }
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriMatchResult = ApplicationCRUD.sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        //case Table1
        if(uriMatchResult == Table1CRUD.INCOMING_COLLECTION_URI_INIDICATOR ||uriMatchResult == Table1CRUD.INCOMING_SINGLE_URI_INDICATOR )
        {
            return table1CRUD.delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
        case Table2
        else if(uriMatchResult == Table2.INCOMING_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR|| uriMatchResult ==Table2.INCOMING_SINGLE_URI_INDICATOR){
            return table2CRUD.delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }

        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri "+uri);
        }
    }
```

Now I am using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a private class in the `ContentProvider` 
and I define an instance of it in my `ContentProvider`. Should I modify the interface and supply each CRUD method that object `Dependency Injection` to let each function use it to access the database? I also want to know what you think about this approach: Is it good enough? Does it make the thing I am trying to do efficiently? What modification can I do to improve this design?

Comment: Do **NOT** spam unrelated questions with comments that are merely links here. Somebody with your experience on StackOverflow should know better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Google IO Schedule](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider) application is a good resource if you are need to design a `ContentProvider` with multiple tables. It sounds like you want to do something a bit more complicated, but maybe it will help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you,but I've been trying to find any example on how to handle CRUD operations when you have master-datail tables, e.g., author-books, order-detail, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything. The ContentProvider's `insert` method is an example , it only takes two parameters : Uri and `ContentValues`. I don't know what to do in this case as I clearly need to pass two `URI`s and perhaps something more elaborate than a single `ContenteValues` object. Do you know that any resource I can use as a guide?

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the opensource project, in which they have used multiple tables. You can look at the various projects of [OpenIntents](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/) and here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338802/can-i-perform-this-android-query-with-contentresolver-query-left-join-and-ca/6548733#6548733).
I hope, it can help you .

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make multiple tables under a content provider this way.

Suppose you have two tables named A and B, their URI's would be AUTHORITY/A, AUTHORITY/B

```
private static final int TableOne = 1; 
private static final int TableTwo = 2;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
       uriMatcher.addUri(AUTHORITY,"A",TableOne);
       uriMatcher.addUri(AUTHORITY,"B",TableTwo);
     }
```

Now you can implement the overridden methods using a standard switch case , and mapping correctly to the underlying SQLite Database class's methods.