# Own ContentProvider with SQLite and multiple tables

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am reading [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider) on implementing my own ContentProvide for working with SQLite. Int the ContentProvider.query there are a few thing that puzzles me. It seems very hardcoded to just one table (the todo table in the tutorial), but maybe Im just not getting it? Now if I wanted to query another table, lets say nodo, how would I change the ContentProvider?

Should I append the table names somehow in queryBuilder.setTables(String inTables)?

What about the CONTENT_TYPE and CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, should there be one for each table?

That about the TODO and TODO_ID varibles and the switch in the query method?

It seems I need to have a lot of if/switch conditions to support multiple tables with the same ContentProvider, is this the way to go or am I on a wrong path?

Thank you

Søren

Comment: 1. setTables... It depends on your needs if you need join you should but still point 2...   2. Content mime... Yes 3. Again for every table. 4. Wrong path... No i think that a good path...  You can try to search/write some kind of generator  fx http://selvin.pl/autocontent.zip <= its mine but its not support views yet only Tables

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Now if I wanted to query another table, lets say nodo, how would I change the ContentProvider?

Querying a new table would mean that you need to add a new `Uri`, since the `Uri` selects the datasource, similar to using a different table.

You would be adding essentially all the hardcoded values that are already there for the todos for your other table. For example:

```
// ------- usually the same for all
private static final String AUTHORITY = "de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider";

// ------- define some Uris
private static final String PATH_TODOS = "todos";
private static final String PATH_REMINDERS = "reminders";

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_TODOS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
    + "/" + PATH_TODOS);
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_REMINDERS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
        + "/" + PATH_REMINDERS);

// ------- maybe also define CONTENT_TYPE for each

// ------- setup UriMatcher
private static final int TODOS = 10;
private static final int TODO_ID = 20;
private static final int REMINDERS = 30;
private static final int REMINDERS_ID = 40;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
  sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH_TODOS, TODOS);
  sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH_TODOS + "/#", TODO_ID);
  sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH_REMINDERS, REMINDERS);
  sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH_REMINDERS + "/#", REMINDERS_ID);
}

//@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // Using SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {

        case TODO_ID:
            // Adding the ID to the original query
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            //$FALL-THROUGH$
        case TODOS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO);
            break;

        case REMINDERS_ID:
            // Adding the ID to the original query
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(ReminderTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            //$FALL-THROUGH$
        case REMINDERS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(ReminderTable.TABLE_REMINDER);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
  }
```

> Should I append the table names somehow in queryBuilder.setTables(String inTables)?

Yes, if different `Uri`s read from different tables then set the table based on the Uri match.

> What about the CONTENT_TYPE and CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, should there be one for each table?

Depends on the actual content type. If they are different and you need a type yes. But you don't need to have them at all. That example defines them but doesn't even use them. It would need to return the type in `getType`, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29).

> That about the TODO and TODO_ID varibles and the switch in the query method?

Those are constants defined for the `UriMatcher` which is explained nicely [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html). It's basically a simplification for String matching. A big `ContentProvider` can have 100 different Uris and selecting the right table in `query` would be painful if you would have to write `if (uri.getPath().equals("todos") { /* code */ } else if (uri..` all the way.

Comment: hi, how would you implement the delete method in this case? can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881758/contentprovider-with-multiple-tables/14779606#14779606) to your question, using UriMatcher, you can implement multiple tables in a content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Content type and content item can be as follows and they can be wrapped in a separate class for each table

`public static final String GENERAL_CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.myfirstapp.db.member" ;
    public static final String SPECIFIC_CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.myfirstapp.db.member" ;`

`vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.yourownanything.anything.tablename'

this defines the general content type
`vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.anthingasabove.table'
this also defines the specific and it is constant to any app those strings(words) vnd.android.cursor.dir and .item must be like that and after /vnd. must be like that

and in the class that extends contentprovider you just uset the same instance of UriMatcher to map the tables