# Content provider for multiple tables

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I am new in Android  and am implementing a content provider for 5 tables.
My Questions Are:
Should I have a Content Provider for each table or  multiple tables in a single 
Content provider? Since the Content Provider  has a  single insert, update, query, delete methods.

How can I include only  one Content Provider in my application? I have searched and  in Most of the  examples, I only find a single table apps.

Where do I have to use switch conditions to support multiple tables with the same Content Provider?

please give me some idea.

Comment: single insert, update, query, delete these methods ask for table name right?. what is the issue then

Comment: i want to insert or delete or update in more than one table but content provider have only have one insert,one delete ... method so how can i do it

Comment: Why dont you call these methods multiple times for each table?

Comment: how to call these method multiple times, please give some example, actually i am new to android so donot have more idea about it , as this is my ist application.    @AndroidEnthusiast

Comment: same way u are calling single time, Use for loop instead, change method argument.

Comment: whether i should call these methods by using loop or i have to use  UriMatcher and for each method i have switch case where each table has 2 case:    switch (uriType) {
        case TUTORIAL_ID: ,case TUTORIALS}                          @ AndroidEnthusiast

Comment: possible duplicate of [Own ContentProvider with SQLite and multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572352/own-contentprovider-with-sqlite-and-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URI parameter:

```
List<String> android.net.Uri.getPathSegments()
```

If your URI is, for example:

```
content://com.mypackage.MyContentProvider/MyTable
```

`MyTable` will be in the list returned by `getPathSegments();`.

Then you have to specify your table in the URI and in insert, update, query, delete methods in provider build a query depending on the URI parameter.

To avoid testing on URI you can add to you provider an **Abstract** method called `getTableName()` witch will return your `tableName` as `String`.

Then extend your provider to 5 classes `Table1Provider`, `Table2Provider` etc. and implement method

```
Class abstract  MyProvider extends ContentProvider{

public abstract String getTableName();

 @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

   ///...
    // Set the table
    queryBuilder.setTables(getTableName());

    //...
    return cursor;
  }
}

class Table1Provider extend MyProvider{

public String getTableName(){
   return "Table1";
}
```

Then instantiate the `Table1Provider` instead of the abstract provider.

Comment: means i have to write all these method  using switch case. like TODO and TODO_ID for 5 table  have   10 cases ???

Comment: what's the problem with using switch statements?

Comment: using switch statements for this example isn't a problem but if you have a more complex example (witch is the case in general) you will have a lot of "switching" witch isn't "elegant" in an object language

Answer (score 0):

Make one provider. Use the URIMatcher class provided by Android to match content URIs with different tables.

Read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI