# Addressing multiple instances of SQLiteOpenHelper when there are multiple Content Providers for a single database

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my app, I have implemented multiple content providers for a single db, one per table, as there are a lot of tables and having the logic of all of them in a single content provider is going to be quite messy.

I followed the advice given by Simo in this link:

[Content provider for multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807795/content-provider-for-multiple-tables)

So there is an abstract AbsShopContentProvider that has a SQLiteOpenHelper member variable. This abstract content provider is then extended by multiple content providers like Table1Provider, Table2Provider,...

So now I have one instance of my SQLiteOpenHelper per Content Provider. Will this create any issues regarding thread safety?

Is it a good idea to make this SQLiteOpenhelper variable "static" in my abstract Content Provider and create an instance of it in onCreate() of the Abstract Provider only if it is null? Will it solve the issue of having many DB helper objects?

Comment: Its a good idea to make `SQLiteOpenhelper` a lazy singleton.

Comment: it will create issue if your db Connection is open and you will try to open the onnection again it will throw the exception

Comment: okie..but I thought Content Provider would solve the problem of connections...though I haven't tried doing it myself! Thanks for both the answers....I'll now remove static and rather implement my SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton....so that when multiple content providers access it, only one instance is made available..

Comment: btw S.D. >> why do we need "lazy" singleton here? Could you explain a bit more on this? why lazy?

Comment: @S.D.  Though I have implemented SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton...not sure what exactly a lazy singleton is. I have implemented it as the standard Singleton pattern. Could you explain regarding the question I asked on Jul 7 (my previous comment...I didn't know that @ is required to intimate the person who answers in stack overflow :) and kept waiting for your answer)...

Comment: @user2557600 added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to make sure that you share one instance of `SQLiteDatabase` , SQLite automatically takes care of locking for same database.

To make a database globally available, extend Application class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

and add it to manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
```

Now, you can access the database from any Activity/Fragment/Service by calling `App.getDb()`

Comment: well, I have implemented multiple content Providers having reference to a singleton SQLiteOpenHelper (that is, a class extending it). It works for me currently, though my way is the longer approach.  -I just wanted to ask about the "lazy" part of your previous answer.  Also, your approach of creating a static db variable inside App is a simpler one.    Well, in my original post, I had followed a similar way by creating a static instance of my custom SQLiteOpenHelper in my Base ContentProvider from which other content providers were extending. So that would also have solved the problem.

Comment: @user2557600 A lazy singleton creates its static instance variable when `getInstance()` is called for the first time. Also, `Application` class is created first and destroyed last in any android Application. So, its `onCreate()` will run before anything else runs. The other advantage is a simple static call `App.getDb()` from anywhere outside.

Comment: yup...that's true. :)

Comment: onTerminate won't get called on released apps. In fact it only gets called on the emulator.